# Sample data from defined interval in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, sampling, confidence-interval

Assuming my data normally distributed I defined a *pseudo* confidence area in an area of my data, considering only the coloured points. I called the upper bound *ub* and the lower bound *lb*.
[image]

I want to sample my data within that ellipse, I did it in this way:

```py
sampled_ids = pd_pca.loc[
    pd_pca.pc1.between(pd_pca_stats.loc['pc1', 'lb'], pd_pca_stats.loc['pc1', 'ub']) & \
    pd_pca.pc2.between(pd_pca_stats.loc['pc2', 'lb'], pd_pca_stats.loc['pc2', 'ub'])] \
.sample(10)
```

The approach above, however, is not totally correct, because it samples from a square and not from an ellipse.
Do you have a good approach to sample my data from the ellipse?

Comment: You need to write down your ellipse equation and mask the points inside its area. Same as you are doing here with a box mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mask for the ellipse. Let's assumed its centered on `(x,y)` with semi axes `(a,b)`, and assuming that the main axes of your ellipse follow the Cartesian axes (otherwise you need to compose with a rotation).

Then your mask will be

```py
ellipse_mask = (pd_pca_stats.loc['pc1'] - x)**2/a**2 + (pd_pca_stats.loc['pc2'] - y)**2/b**2 <= 1
sampled_ids = pd_pca[ellipse_mask].sample(10)
```

Comment: Looks a really nice answer! just a question: atm I set the rotation angle by hand, however I'd like to calculate it. I tried with Theta = Arccos(Corr), but doesn't seem correct. do you have any hints?

Comment: Arctan is probably the function you are looking for

Comment: Nice, thanks, what if I have more than 2 axis? how would the ellipsoid equation change?